# How to show in bash script the release of a Red Hat distribution

Tags: bash, redhat, rhel7

I have a bash script where I request to add a repository related to the current release I'm running, I have define my variable this way:

```
RedHat_VER=`rpm -qi --whatprovides /etc/redhat-release | awk '/Version/ {print $3}'`
```

but in this way I get, i.e. "7.6" but I need to get "7", how can I do that?

Thanks to all who can help me.
Best regards,

Alessandro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RHEL7:

```
. /etc/os-release
echo "${VERSION_ID%.*}"
```

Output:

```
7
```

Comment: Probably the most bulletproof method (I believe /etc/os-release is standardized)

Comment: Thank @Cyrus, this way work like a charm and I also do not need to install rehat-lsb so it sounds very good!!!

Comment: Fails for RHEL systems which are really  '7Server'.  Som solutions gets me '7' others '7.9'.   Really I have no found a solution that is global.  some better one work for "yum" while others work for "dnf",  nothing universal!  Arrgghhh...

Comment: @anthony: This might help: `rpm -qi --whatprovides /etc/redhat-release | sed -nE ' s/Version *: ([0-9]+).*/\1/p'`

Comment: @Cyrus: no sorry that only returns '7', and not 7Server.  The best solution I found so far is to list the directory /var/cache/yum/*/ which returns  7Server   But that is a side effect!   The value is vital for correct repo handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsb_release -r`. The output will be something like this, which is easily parsable:

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:        6.10
$
```

And you can make it easier by using `-s` (check `man lsb_release`):

```
$ lsb_release -rs
6.10
$
```

Comment: It does. You probably need to ```sudo yum install redhat-lsb-core```, the package that provides it.

Comment: Here is another way: ```sudo rpm -q --queryformat='%{VERSION}' redhat-release-server```.

Comment: BTW, I got the name of the package from the top of my head. Use the right package name and it will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ lsb_release -rs | cut -d. -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way :

```
rpm -qia '*release*' | grep Version | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | cut -d'.' -f1
```

Another way :

```
cat /etc/redhat-release | cut -d'.' -f1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```